# Previewing fields of a referenced node in Drupal 7 with EntityRefererence

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, entityreference

I'm confronted with the following  not-knowing-how-to-do-this:

Two content types (CT) : Parent and Child

Parent has a field ChildRef (Field type: Entity Reference; Widget: Select list)

Child has fields Name (Text) , Adress(Text) and so on

When I create a new Parent node, I can select one of the Child nodes  (no problem there, the Select list nicely displays the titles of the Child nodes)

What I need is that while editing the Parent, I'd like to preVIEW (no editing there) the fields of the Child, displayed inline, below the Select list.

Of course, once the Parent node is saved, there are many ways to display the Child node inside the Parent node. But it's the preVIEW in the Parent's edit mode that I need.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Entity Reference View Widget](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference_view_widget)

Then in the child content type, manage the display of fields for the widget.